# Asp.Net MVC Ativar breakpoint instrução Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Quando executo o sistema ele não respeita o breakpoint e apresenta essa mensagem como mostra a imagem.

Segundo essa documentação da microsoft deveria funcionar assim.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2019

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, EU nunca tentei debugar pelo Visual studio, se não me engano só é possível se você rodar o site pelo IE, você consegue fazer isso com mais facilidade pelo Console (F12) no Chrome ou Firefox

Comment: Tentei pelo IE mas também não funcionou. Como você faz para debugar?

Comment: Abre a url do Localhost com o Chrome e aperta F12.

Comment: @PedroMapelli Conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: Pelo Visual Studio não, na verdade de certa forma sim, eu começo a debuggar pelo console do navegador, coloco os breakpoints pelo navegador, e ai posso continuar pelo Visual Studio...

Answer (score 0):

No Visual Studio 2019, acredito que esse recurso já exista desde o 2017, basta você habilitar a opção de `Script Debugging`.

Porém ele só vai parar nos breakpoints de scripts contidos em arquivos `.js` ou `.ts`. E se você utilizar como browser o Chrome ou IE/Edge.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se essa opção não estiver presente na IDE, junto ao start, você pode ir em `Debug > Options` e habilitar a opção por lá

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]